# Masturbation with word porn allowed?

Tags: halal-haram

I can’t control my urges please help. Is word porn haram?, and is masturbation without visuals haram?

Answer (score 0):

Masturbation in general is haram in Islam you should repent to Allah and ask for forgiveness and never do this again if you feel the desire to do it remember Allah is always watching.